# Debug Mode Stats?

Tags: spacechem

If you hit <kbd>F5</kbd>, you turn on some debugging stuff at the top of the screen.

FPS is frames per second and Drawn Editors seems to be associated with the number of overlay windows, but I have no idea what the other stuff is.

Anybody have any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure for SpaceChem, but this is one of the possibilities:

Bind calls are open functions in the programming code. For example, a background music playing, might be a function in a function, in a function, in a function, in a method etc etc.. This is a certain amount of bind calls.

Unfortunately, I really do not have a clue what Locals and User can mean..